# How to query 2 different tables with only one query in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have two models called `One` and `Two`. Both models have an attribute called `producer`. I am querying them using the following code:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> producer = 'something'
>>> a = One.objects.filter(producer=producer)
>>> b = Two.objects.filter(producer=producer)
>>> results = list(chain(a, b))
>>> len(connection.queries)
2
```

Unfortunately, this approach hits my database twice, as the length shows. How can I do this using just one single query. I have lots of different models, and I want to query them all at once in a view. Hitting the database once will greatly help performance. I have no need to sort anything, and the filters themselves are the same for all the models.

Edit: Due to an answer below, I feel its wise to add this, my models look like this:

```
class Number(models.Model):
     producer = models.CharField(max_length=255)

     class Meta:
         abstract = True

class One(Number):
     ...

class Two(Number):
     ...
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no way, as far as I'm aware, to directly accomplish that.

One approach that might work, however, is to build your models in a way where they both share this field from a model they inherit. For example:

```
class Number(models.Model):
    # common fields among objects of type One, Two, etc
    producer = ...

class One(Number):
    # other exclusive fields specifically for objects of type One

class Two(Number):
    # other exclusive fields specifically for objects of type Two
```

Then you would be able to query the `Number` model directly with

```
Number.objects.filter(producer=producer)
```

to obtain all the results for all objects, whether they are type `One` or `Two`.

Although note that making two queries for getting data from two tables is not necessarily a bad thing, and unless the amount of queries you end up with is significantly large/the different models do have a lot in common, it might not be worth the trouble.

Comment: What if the `Number` class was abstract?

Comment: I don't believe you can query an abstract class like that, so it likely won't work. Having an abstract class essentially brings you back to your current setup since two separate tables are created internally, just with more compact code.

Comment: So basically there is no way to do this without writing raw SQL?

Comment: You can not make ```query``` using abstract ```Model```. First of all abstract ```Model``` does not have ```objects``` attribute (It raises ```AttributeError``` as well as you perform ```Number.objects.filter(**lookup_kwargs)```). Even, if you try instanstiate ```QuerySet``` directly (avoid ```Manager```), ```QuerySet(Number)``` this will raise ```ProgrammingError```. You can not querying using Abstract base class.